# Docker on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I try to install docker on my Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS.
I know how to use basic things on linux but not much in details. Thats why i followed following tutorial:

https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/

On last step (where I try to install docker-ce)

```
sudo apt-get install docker-ce
```

i get following error:

> docker-ce (18.03.1~ce-0~ubuntu) wird eingerichtet ... Job for
>   docker.service failed because the control process exited with error
>   code. See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for
>   details.
>
> invoke-rc.d: initscript docker, action "start" failed.
>
> ●
>   docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
>
> Loaded: loaded
>   (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled) 
>   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Mo
>   2018-05-07 15:53:45 CEST; 5ms ago
>   Docs: https://docs.docker.com
>   Process: 6784 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
>   Main PID: 6784 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
>   Memory: 32.1M
>   CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service 
>   dpkg: error on executing
>   Paketes docker-ce (--configure): post-installation-Skript returned error 1 on executing:  docker-ce
>   E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned
>   an error code (1)

I tried to fix it by myself and here some informations which was required in diffrent forums:

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list:
```

deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu xenial stable

```
dpkg --configure -a
```

same error like above (and i have no idea for what this comannd is responsible)

Answer (score 0):

Try following the below steps and let me know if you have any issues.

```
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
sudo apt-get update
apt-cache policy docker-ce
sudo apt-get install -y docker-ce
sudo systemctl status docker
```

Comment: sorry for the late answer. unfortunately it doesnt works. I get the same output like in my Question :(

Comment: @NicoSchuck can you check the logs "/var/log/syslog"

Comment: also you can do the following.Remove /var/lib/docker (rm -rf /var/lib/docker). Restart Docker.